# control sentence-end spacing in vim when using line wrap

Tags: vim

In vim when I'm adjusting wrapping in paragraphs of prose, it adds 2 spaces between sentences. For example:

```
This is one sentence.
This is another sentence.
```

If I highlight these two lines and type `gw` it becomes:

```
This is one sentence.  This is another sentence.
```

Two spaces after the period. Is there a way to change the behavior of vim to only use 1 space after the period?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [`'joinspaces'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27joinspaces%27) option. It's on by default, so to only have a single space, you need to put

```
set nojoinspaces
```

into your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Great, that did the trick!